# How to upload file using php API

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter-3

I am using codeigniter 3 , i have created folder in root name as uploads/profile_pics.
Now using jquery ajax function am sending json data to api server , without json data i can't store data into data base , without json data my data storing blank in database table.

i have collected file like `var profile = document.getElementById('profile').value;` and send it to php api server using AJAX , I am not using formdata because it's not helpful for me.

```
$.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo base_url();?>api/get_subscription",
        type:"POST",
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        processData:false,
        contentType: false,
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify({type:type,reg_no:reg_no, profile:profile}),
            complete: function(data){
                        alert("success");

                }
```

my php api is below

```
public function get_subscription(){
        $json=file_get_contents("php://input");
        $obj=json_decode($json,true);
        $posts=$this->api_model->get_subscription($obj);    
        header('Content-type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($posts);
    }
```

and in api modal

```
if(!empty($profile)){
                $profile_pic_decode = base64_decode($profile);
                $file_name = 'profile'.time().'.png';
                $url = base_url().'uploads/profile_pics/'.$file_name;
                $file = 'uploads/profile_pics/'.$file_name;
                file_put_contents($file, $profile_pic_decode);    
            }
```

i am getting file in upload folder but it can't be open

Comment: what do you mean can't be open?  open for what? view or write?

Comment: if you want to use AJAX or REST API to upload your file, you have to use FormData or if you want to solve your problem immediately with JSON, I suggest you use this :

https://github.com/LegenD1995/foxyntax_ci